# Nape Physics: Collision issue (moving across tiles)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, starling-framework, physics-engine, nape

There is a character, when moved across one tile to another sometimes the character either jumps over the meeting point of the tile polygons or becomes completely stuck and can no longer move in the direction they were going until they take a step back.

( video of issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLAAHyinOVE )

( Interactive demo of issue: http://snkygames.com/InputSceneTest )

Has anyone else met with this issue? Any solution suggestions.

The issue still occurs if I allow body rotation.
The issue still occurs if I use a rectangle as a polygon instead of a circle.

Code:

```
//character
//material: elasticity=0.650, frictionDynamic=0.570, frictionStatic=1.200, density=1.000, frictionRolling=0.000
<body>.shapes.add(new Circle(16, null, <material>));
var vel:Vec2 = <body>.velocity;
<body>.velocity = Vec2.weak(vel.x + +/-2000.000 * 0.020, vel.y + 0.000);

//nape
<gravity> = new Vec2(0.000, 400.000);
<space>.step(***, 10, 10);

//rectangle tile
//material: elasticity=0.000, frictionDynamic=1.000, frictionStatic=1.000, density=1.000, frictionRolling=0.000
<body>.shapes.add(new Polygon(Polygon.box(<width>, <height>), <material>));
```